# Select rows after the current row which are null and combine them to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written the following SQL code to display the data as rows, where the row after data is having null values except on the description column.

```
DECLARE @StudentData TABLE
(
  RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  RemarksDate NVARCHAR(20),
  StudentName NVARCHAR(1000),
 Description NVARCHAR(MAX),
  TotStudents NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @StudentData(RemarksDate, StudentName, Description, TotStudents)
VALUES('2/1/2021', NULL, 'Poor In English', '14'),
(NULL, NULL, '1 ABC', NULL),
(NULL, NULL, '1 XYZ', NULL),
(NULL, NULL, '1 MNO', NULL),
(NULL, NULL, '1 IGH', NULL),
(NULL, NULL, '10 KKK', NULL),
('2/1/2021', NULL, 'Poor In Maths', '5'),
(NULL, NULL, '5 PQR', NULL),
('2/8/2021', NULL, 'Poor In Social', '1'),
(NULL, NULL, '1 RST', NULL)
```

This results in the output as follows:

[image]

I have written the following query to group and display rows:

```
SELECT t1.RemarksDate, LTRIM(RIGHT(t2.Description, LEN(t2.Description) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0- 9]%', t2.Description ))) StudentName, t1.Description
 ,LEFT(t2.Description, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', t2.Description ))
 FROM (
 SELECT *, RowID + TotStudents MaxVal
 FROM @StudentData
 WHERE RemarksDate is NOT NULL
 ) t1 
  JOIN (
   SELECT * 
   FROM @StudentData
   WHERE RemarksDate is NULL
  ) t2 ON t2.RowId BETWEEN t1.RowID and t1.MaxVal
```

The data is displayed as follows

[image]

Expected output is as follows

```
2/1/2021    ABC Poor In English 1
2/1/2021    XYZ Poor In English 1
2/1/2021    MNO Poor In English 1
2/1/2021    IGH Poor In English 1
2/1/2021    KKK Poor In English 10
2/1/2021    PQR Poor In Maths   5
2/8/2021    RST Poor In Social  1
```

Comment: Why is student name stored in description? Why aren't students stored in another table?

Comment: I am dumping the data from excel to a table, I will get the excel in a non formatted version

Comment: Please explain the logic for each column.  It is not obvious.

Comment: The initial data will be the same as per in the first image.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the fact that the table design is pretty awful, I would suggest the following approach:

```
WITH cteRemarks AS(
  SELECT *, LEAD(RowId) OVER (ORDER BY RowID) AS RowIdNxt
    FROM @StudentData
    WHERE TotStudents IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT r.RemarksDate
      ,RIGHT(t.Description, LEN(t.Description)-CHARINDEX(' ', t.Description)) AS StudentsName
      ,r.Description AS Description
      ,LEFT(t.Description, CHARINDEX(' ', t.Description)-1) AS Val
  FROM cteRemarks r
  LEFT JOIN @StudentData t ON t.TotStudents IS NULL
                           AND t.RowID > r.RowID
                           AND t.RowID < ISNULL(r.RowIDNxt, 99999999)
```

Comment: Hi how to handle when negative values are there?

Answer (score 2):

**This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.** There are many solutions, I will give you one that only requires a single scan of the base table.

We have a header row and child rows, and we need to apply the header row values to the child rows.

We can solve this by defining the start point of each group, then taking windowed header values for each group and finally filtering out the header rows

```sql
WITH Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
        GroupId = MAX(CASE WHEN Description LIKE 'Poor%' THEN RowID END)
             OVER (ORDER BY RowID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM @StudentData s
),
GroupValues AS (
    SELECT
        RemarksDate = MAX(CASE WHEN Description LIKE 'Poor%' THEN RemarksDate END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId),
        DescriptionHeader = MAX(CASE WHEN Description LIKE 'Poor%' THEN Description END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId),
        Space = CHARINDEX(' ', Description),
        Description
    FROM Groupings
)
SELECT
    RemarksDate,
    DescriptionHeader,
    StudentName = SUBSTRING(Description, Space + 1, LEN(Description)),
    SomeNumber = LEFT(Description, Space - 1)
FROM GroupValues
WHERE Description NOT LIKE 'Poor%';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8fb5787534e0f0891597fa44c78d4b2)